# meteor-upload custom template callback

Tags: templates, meteor, upload, callback

With the [meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) package's built-in bootstrap template, there is a handy way to have template specific callbacks when the upload is finished

```
<template name="home">
    {{> upload_bootstrap callbacks=myCallbacks }}
</template>`
```

and

```
Template.home.helpers({
    myCallbacks: function() {
        return {
            finished: function(index, fileInfo, context) { ... },
            ...
        }
    }
})
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to do the same thing when defining a custom template [described here](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads#custom-templates) :

```
<template name="customUpload">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" class="jqUploadclass" data-form-data='{{ submitData }}'>
        {{#with infoLabel}}
            {{ infoLabel}} <button class="start">StartUpload</button>
            <div style="width: 200px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid black">
                <div style="background: red; height: 30px; width: {{ progress }}">
                    {{ progress }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/with}}
    </form>
</template>
```

Could somebody help me understand how to run the myCallbacks function from the custom template after the upload is complete?

( say for example adding the fileInfo to different collections depending on which template the uploader is called from )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

HTML:

```
<template name="myContainerTemplate">
  {{> customUpload multiple=true callbacks=myCallbacks}}
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.myContainerTemplate.helpers({
    myCallbacks: function() {
        return {
            finished: function(index, fileInfo, context) { ... },
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

You have to attach the helper to the parent template.